# Powershell output not formatting properly

Tags: powershell

I'm using this script to get some basic info from virtual machines on our HyperV cluster:

```
#Establish global variables and MasterList array
$VMList = Get-VM
$MasterList = @()

#Loop through VMs and get Name, Processor count, assigned memory, add to MasterList
foreach($vm in $VMList) {
$ALLVHD = Get-VHD $vm.harddrives.path -ComputerName $vm.computername
$MyObject = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
    Name = ($vm).VMName
    ProcessorCount = (Get-VMProcessor $vm).Count
    AssignedMemory = ($vm).MemoryAssigned
    DiskType = $VHD.VhdType
    'Total(GB)' = [math]::Round($VHD.Size/1GB)
    'Used(GB)' = [math]::Round($VHD.FileSize/1GB)
    'Free(GB)' =  [math]::Round($VHD.Size/1GB- $VHD.FileSize/1GB)
}

$MasterList += $MyObject
}
$MasterList | Out-GridView
```

It mostly works, but there are several problems.  The column order is wrong, it outputs DiskType,Name,AssignedMemory,Free(GB),ProcessorCount,Used(GB),Total(GB) and I have no idea why because that's now how it's ordered in the code.  Also, the Free,Used, and Total amounts are 71, 29, and 100 for all items when that is incorrect.

If any Powershell experts can help me with this, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: See [Change order of columns in the object](//stackoverflow.com/a/19625107).

Comment: Where did you assign value to `$VHD`?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, thanks for the suggestions

```
#Establish global variables and MasterList array
$VMList = Get-VM
$MasterList = @()

#Loop through all VMs on node
foreach($vm in $VMList) {

    $ALLVHD = Get-VHD $vm.HardDrives.path -ComputerName $vm.computername

    foreach($VHD in $ALLVHD){
                $MyObject = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                    Name = $vm.Name
                    DiskType = $VHD.VhdType
                    Path = $VHD.Path
                    'Total(GB)' = [math]::Round($VHD.Size/1GB)
                    'Used(GB)' = [math]::Round($VHD.FileSize/1GB)
                    'Free(GB)' =  [math]::Round($VHD.Size/1GB- $VHD.FileSize/1GB)
                    ProcessorCount = (Get-VMProcessor $vm).Count
                    AssignedMemory = ($vm).MemoryAssigned        
                 }
    #Add information to MasterList array
    $Masterlist += $MyObject
    }
}

#Change this line to print output however you want
$MasterList | select Name,DiskType,Path,'Total(GB)','Used(GB)','Free(GB)',ProcessorCount,@{Expression={$_.AssignedMemory/1GB};Label="AssignedMemory(GB)"}
```